# Upload a Pdf file to another website using cURL

Tags: php, json, api, curl, file-upload

Specifically relating to this particular thread [Upload a file to a website using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844258/upload-a-file-to-a-website-using-php) I want to implement this using cURL on PHP.

How do I set this up?

Below is what I have tried.

Note I just edited this by adding the codes I have tried.

```
<?php


 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

 $errors= array();//
 $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']; 
 $size = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']; 
 $type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']; 
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']; 
 $upload_ok =1;
 $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['fileToUpload'] 
 ['name'])));//



 $extensions= array("pdf","jpeg","jpg","png");

 $jj = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
 $mj = base64_encode($jj);

 if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
  $errors[]="vvvvv.";
 } 

 if($size >= xxx){
  $errors[]='xxx;'
 }

 if(empty($errors)==true){


  echo  "Success </br>";


  $request  = "xxxxxxxxx";

  $headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx",
     "Content-type => multipart/form-data",


     "Accept:application/json",
  );





  $data = [

     'voucher_data' => 'base64_encode($tmp_name)',

   'callback_url' => 'xxxxxxxxx'
  ];




  $curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  $data,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);


  var_dump($response);


  }else{
  print_r($errors);
  }




?>
```

I tried using curl_file_create($mj) as suggested below but on var_dump...it says bool(false)

Comment: Please provide example codes what you've did so far. And please read more on how to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of trying out different methods I passed this value to the post field directly without using it as array

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => “foo=$mj&callbackurl=url”,
```

and it worked. This was where I was stucked. I did it the other way and it didn't work. Each situation is unique. Someone could also need this.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to make a request that uploads a file to another server other than your own.

After PHP 5.5, there is a function named `curl_file_create` and as the name suggests, it's being used for uploading files.

```
$post = array (
    'extra_info' => '123456', // If required.. like user_id for avatar
    'file_contents' => curl_file_create ('path/to/file');
);

$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

If you don't want to use that then there is a much simple way:

```
$args = [];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$args['file'] = '@/path/to/file';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: I edited my question again and posted the code there. it shows var_dump bool false.

Comment: do not suggest the `@` method anymore, it has been deprecated since PHP 5.5, disabled-by-default since PHP 5.6, and completely removed in PHP 7.0, every version of PHP where the `@` method works has been end-of-life for years.